# Removing rows by date in R - Financial data

Tags: r, date, dataframe, time-series, subset

I am currently working on my master's thesis. In my dataset I have daily observation of 5413 companies for 15 years. I need to remove non trading days i.e. holidays at London Stock Exchange such as Christmas, New years etc . I have referred to 'Removing rows containing specific dates in R' but couldn't find solution to my prblem
My data set has closing prices of stocks and looks as follows (has the same data format)

```
Date          A       B
31/12/1999  NA        NA
03/01/2000  NA        NA
04/01/2000  79.5      325
05/01/2000  79.5      322.5
06/01/2000  NA       NA   
07/01/2000   79.5   327.5
```

And for example I want to remove dates 31/12/1999 and 06/01/2000 so that my data looks like

```
Date        A         B
03/01/2000  NA        NA
04/01/2000  79.5    325
05/01/2000  79.5    322.5  
07/01/2000  79.5    327.5
```

I'm new to R but this stackoverflow has been very helpful. I thank you in advance

Comment: In timeDate package, there is a function holidayNYSE() that you can supply years of interest as a vector and it will return a vector of holiday dates for those years, Then, you can subset your data with not %in% filter. Example use: library(timeDate); holidayNYSE(c(2013, 2014, 2015));

Comment: Thank you for your reply but I'm working on London Stock Exchange, which has some different non-trading days (holidays) from NYSE. I ran the code as you have given but there nothing for London Stock Exchange.

Comment: Use holidayLONDON instead from the same package. :)

Comment: You can specify a wide range of years like this, without enumerating every year using the catenation I showed above. Look at the documentation of the package and the methods. holidayLONDON(1990:2015);

Comment: Sorry my bad I was looking by LSE. Thank you  I have got the vector of holidays. Kindly, can you please explain how to use %in% now. As I mentioned I'm new to R but I'm a quick learner. I thank you in advance.

Comment: Assuming you have a data frame called 'df', you can use df[!df$Date %in% holidayLONDON(1999:2015), ] to obtain the subset data frame.

Comment: Hard to help without the relevant code you are running. Make sure the date column is in date format. Post a reproducible example (look up on stackoverflow what it means).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that your column Date is a character vector, you could just modify the answer provided by user3949008 in the comments, specifying inside holidayLONDON the years you need:

```
df$Date <- as.Date(df$Date,"%d/%m/%Y")
df[!df$Date %in% as.Date(holidayLONDON(1999:2000)), ]
```

Output:

```
        Date    A     B
1 1999-12-31   NA    NA
3 2000-01-04 79.5 325.0
4 2000-01-05 79.5 322.5
5 2000-01-06   NA    NA
6 2000-01-07 79.5 327.5
```

Data:

```
df <- structure(list(Date = c("31/12/1999", "03/01/2000", "04/01/2000", 
"05/01/2000", "06/01/2000", "07/01/2000"), A = c(NA, NA, 79.5, 
79.5, NA, 79.5), B = c(NA, NA, 325, 322.5, NA, 327.5)), .Names = c("Date", 
"A", "B"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

Comment: Thank you to mpalanco and user3949008. Figured out the right code from the above suggestions                                                      library(timeDate)
Price$Date <- as.Date(Price$Date,"%Y-%m-%d")
Price <-Price[!Price$Date %in% as.Date(holidayLONDON(1999:2014)), ]

Comment: @Aquarius Glad it was helpful. Cheers